# Mudar o MainActivity por outro ao Clicar num botão Switch e manter a alteração

Tags: android

Preciso que ao clicar num Switch Button, a MainActivity.kt seja trocada por outra activity chamada ActivityDois.java e que a opção seja mantida. 
E apenas se o usuário clicar novamente no Switch Button, o MainActivity.kt original é restaurado.

---

**Questão:** Como trocar a MainActivty por outra classe e manter está opção mesmo reiniciando o app?

---

**MainActivity.kt**

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

---

**ActivityDois.java**

```
public class ActivityDois extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dois);

 }
```

Comment: Bom dia amigo, você apenas tem que salvar o state da Activity. Segue link que vai te ajudar bastante. [How to save ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentre vários jeitos possíveis, eu usaria as `SharedPreferences`.

Cheque seu botão switch e salve qual tipo você quer manter através das preferências.

```
 Switch swt = findViewById(R.id.swt);

        if (swt.isChecked()) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("MainActivity", "ActivityDois"); 
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("MainActivity", "MainActivity");
            editor.apply();
        }
```

E ao iniciar o app novamente, cheque qual activity está salva como a inicial

```
 //aqui você recupera a preferência e inicia a activity que quiser
SharedPreferences activity = getSharedPreferences("MainActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(activity.equals("ActivityDois"))
//startActivity ActivityDois... 
else if(activity.equals("MainActivity"))
//startActivity MainActivity...
```

Comment: Gostei da idéia. Como eu posso referenciar o botão do switch?

Comment: @michaelbrayon editei o código pra mostrar